# суммирование столбцов в сводной таблице excel

Tags: excel, pivot

как суммировать два столбца значений в один, без дополнительного столбца в сводной таблице. то есть, чтобы в столбце "касса" было значение "касса + сумма"
[image: то есть, чтобы в столбце "касса" было значение "касса + сумма"]